# Fixing a broken proxy class

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to update some WSE code to use WCF, and I'm running into trouble with one service in particular.  When I generated my proxy class from the WSDL, it creates methods with no parameters or return type.  The parameters were easy enough to fix -- saved the autogenerated `References.cs` file as a new file, added the parameter to both the generated interface and generated client, and it works.  Using Fiddler, I can see that the traffic is as expected.

What I'm finding very vexing is that WCF seems to be just throwing away the response payload.  I can see it coming back over the wire, but it seems to just vanish somewhere in the deep dark crevices of WCF.  No errors or warnings, just gone.

I'm kind of at my wits end here.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how to figure out where the response is going.

The method in the client (this used to return `void`; I've set it to `object[]` in hopes I could get something that I could cast):

```
public object[] getAddress(string user) {
    return base.Channel.getAddress(user);
}
```

The method in the interface:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "https://xxxxxx/Address#getAddress", ReplyAction = "*")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, SupportFaults=true, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
object[] getAddress(string user);
```

The raw XML response (redacted) looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getAddressResponse xmlns="https://xxxxx/Address">
       <ArrayOfAddress arrayType="xsd:Address[3]" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[3]" xsi:type="Array">
        <Address>
          <street xsi:type="xsd:string">3rd</street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
          <street xsi:type="xsd:string">1st</street>
        </Address>
        <Address>
          <street xsi:type="xsd:string">2nd</street>
        </Address>
      </ArrayOfAddress>
    </getAddressResponse>
   </soap:Body>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I was unable to get this resolved, and there are only a few methods on this service, so I ended up just manually interacting with the service using WebClient, bypassing WCF.

Comment: What would the method ideally return?

Comment: I added the response XML to the question.  I'd planned to structure a class structure that is close to that data structure.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `Namespace` to your `OperationContract`? Apparently the xml that comes back is in particular namespace.

Comment: Namespace doesn't appear to be valid on `OperationContract`.

Answer (score 0):

Returning object[] isn't going to give you something you can cast. WCF on the client needs to know the possible concrete types to deserialize the response. I'd expect an exception though.

To fix this you should go ahead and create the Address data contract class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that as well, with no luck.  I also would have expected an exception; that part puzzles me.